# ModbusTCP - wrong ID in generated frame

Tags: c, plc, modbus-tcp

I have weird problem. I try to communicate with ifm AY1020 via modbusTCP using libmodbus from PC.

My code looks as follow:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <modbus/modbus.h>

int main()
{
  modbus_t *ctx;
  uint16_t *tab_reg;
  int rc;
  int i;

  ctx = modbus_new_tcp("192.168.1.250", 502);
  modbus_set_debug(ctx, TRUE);


  tab_reg = (uint16_t *) malloc(5 * sizeof(uint16_t));
  memset(tab_reg, 0, 5 * sizeof(uint16_t));


  if (modbus_connect(ctx) == -1)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Connection failed: %s\n",modbus_strerror(errno));
    modbus_free(ctx);
    return -1;
  }

  rc = modbus_read_registers(ctx, 3002, 2, tab_reg);

  if (rc == -1) 
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", modbus_strerror(errno));
    return -1;
  }

  for (i=0; i < rc; i++) {
    printf("reg[%d]=%d (0x%X)\n", i, tab_reg[i], tab_reg[i]);
   }

  modbus_close(ctx);
  modbus_free(ctx);
}
```

Thanks to debug I was able to get the frame that is generated in  modbus_read_registers function:

> [00][01][00][00][00][06][FF][03][0B][BA][00][02]

And I get this

> ERROR Gateway path unavailable
>   Gateway path unavailable

After analysis you can find that device id in that frame is FF, but according to this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsICa.png) PLC expects 1.

Going further if during debugging I force change this value from FF to 01 everything works fine. It looks like it assign wrong ID.

I would be grateful for any help, advice, solution.

Best,

Paweł

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [the Man](http://libmodbus.org/docs/v3.0.6/modbus_set_slave.html)

You should call `modbus_set_slave` to set a specific destination device.

> **TCP**
>
> The slave number is only required in `TCP` if the message must reach a device on a serial network. The special value `MODBUS_TCP_SLAVE (0xFF)` can be used in `TCP` mode to restore the default value.

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

Your code should be

```
modbus_set_slave(ctx, 1);
rc = modbus_read_registers(ctx, 3002, 2, tab_reg);
```